# Why the volatile Happens-Before order for Instruction Reordering fails?

Tags: java, multithreading, volatile

I hava following code to test **volatile**. `bEnd` and `nCount` are defined volatile.

```
nCount = 0, bEnd = false
```

The Writer thread will set

```
nCount = 100, bEnd = true
```

The Reader thread read these viriables and print them. Base on the Java Happens-before order, in my opinion, **volatile ensures nCount = 100 when bEnd = true**. But sometimes the program print this:

```
main thread done.
thread Reader running ...
thread Writer running ...
SharedData nCount = 0, bEnd = false
thread Writer bEnd = true
thread Reader nCount = 0, bEnd = true
thread Reader nCount = 100, bEnd = true
thread Reader nCount = 100, bEnd = true
thread Reader done.
```

How can the Reader get **"nCount = 0, bEnd = true"** ???

The following code running on windows10, jdk1.8.0_131

```
public class HappensBeforeWithVolatile {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Thread threadWriter = new Thread(new Writer());
        Thread threadReader = new Thread(new Reader());
        threadWriter.start();
        threadReader.start();

        System.out.println("main thread done.");
    }
}

class Writer implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("thread Writer running ...");
        SharedData.nCount = 100;
//        System.out.println("thread Writer nCount = 100");
        SharedData.bEnd = true;
        System.out.println("thread Writer bEnd = true");
    }
}

class Reader implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("thread Reader running ...");
        System.out.println("thread Reader nCount = " + SharedData.nCount + ", bEnd = " + SharedData.bEnd);
        System.out.println("thread Reader nCount = " + SharedData.nCount + ", bEnd = " + SharedData.bEnd);
        if (SharedData.nCount == 0 && SharedData.bEnd) {
            System.out.println("thread Reader CODE REORDER !!!");
        }
        System.out.println("thread Reader nCount = " + SharedData.nCount + ", bEnd = " + SharedData.bEnd);
        System.out.println("thread Reader done.");
    }
}

class SharedData {
    volatile public static boolean bEnd = false;
    volatile public static int nCount = 0;

    static {
        System.out.println("SharedData nCount = " + nCount + ", bEnd = " + bEnd);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**volatile ensures nCount = 100 when bEnd = true**

Technologically, yes. But the reader did not read them atomically. So it might print `nCount = 0 and bEnd = true`.

Here is an example:

1. Reader reads `nCount 0`
2. Wirter writes `nCount = 100`
3. Wirter writes `bEnd = true`
4. Writer prints `thread Writer bEnd = true`
5. Reader reads `bEnd true`

Comment: Nice, precise explanation!

Comment: Thanks! I forgot the reader is not atomically. Change the println() into condition test of bEnd will fix the problem.  if(SharedData.bEnd) { if (SharedData.nCount != 100) {
                new Exception("nCount = " + SharedData.nCount).printStackTrace();
            }

Answer (score 1):

Your entire example is a bit flawed btw. To test that happens-before, you need to test subsequent actions, that is make `bEnd` volatile and `nCount` not a volatile, then simplify your example as:

```
static class Reader implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {

        while (true) {
            if (SharedData.bEnd) {
                System.out.println(SharedData.nCount);
                break;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Not yet seen as true");
                LockSupport.parkNanos(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toNanos(100));
            }
        }
    }
}

static class Writer implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        LockSupport.parkNanos(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toNanos(1000));
        SharedData.nCount = 100;
        SharedData.bEnd = true;

    }
}
```

That will output `100`, always (in this case at least). The correct explanation would be that if a `Reader` Thread sees the update of the `Write` thread of a volatile variable, it will see everything that was done before that, thus `100`.

Comment: Minor: May I ask you the reason you used `LockSupport::park`? I personally trying to avoid using since if it is used incorrectly it may interfere with `park`/`unpark` that is hidden under e.g. `ReentrantLock` wich leads to non quite obvious bugs.

Comment: @St.Antario hmm I am not aware of the `ReentrantLock` thing, might have to look into it. I used it in this example simply because it does not throw a checked exception (unlike `Thread::sleep`)

Comment: @St.Antario well you got my attention now, care to provide a link/question about this? I am really interested, since IIRC we use it in production, so might need to change that code. thank you!

Comment: I can provide you with an issue I myself faced with a couple of months ago when trying to use `LockSupport::park` in our prod-env.

Comment: But this was an example of incorrect usage of `LockSupport::park`. I broke the code after adding logging with logback. Since it uses `ReentrantLock` which interferred with my attempt of parking.